# Big O analysis of Modified Merge Sort (divide by √n arrays, instead 2)

Tags: runtime, big-o, mergesort

I am working on a modified merge sort algorithm using a similar procedure for merging two sorted arrays, but instead want to merge √n sorted arrays of  √n size.  It will start with an array of size n, then recursively be divided into √n sub problems as stated above. The following algorithm is used:

```
1.) Divide array of n elements into  √n pieces
2.) Pass elements back into method for recursion
3.) Compare pieces from step 1
4.) Merge components together to form sorted array
```

I am fairly certain this is the proper algorithm, but I am unsure how to find the Big O run time.  Any guidance in the proper direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might find some information searching for "n-way merge sort". Often 3 and 4 are given as alternative examples to explore. Compared to a standard merge sort, complexity moves *into* "compare pieces from step 1" ..

Comment: I have added some more specifications to clarify, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part is to find the complexity of the merging step. Assuming that an analogous method to that of the 2-way case is used:

- Finding the minimum element out of all `√n` arrays is `O(√n)`.
- This needs to be done for all `n` elements to be merged; possible edge cases when some of the arrays are depleted only contribute a subtracted `O(√n)` in complexity.

Hence the complexity of merging is `O(n√n)`. Expanding the recurrence:

[image]

Where `(*)` marks an expansion of the `T()` terms. Spotting the pattern for the `m`-th expansion:

- Coefficient of `T`-term is `n` to the power of sum of powers of `1/2` up to `m`.
- Argument of `T`-term is `1/2` to the power of `m`.
- Accumulated terms the sum of `n` to the power of 1 + powers of `1/2` up to `m`.

Writing the above rules as a compact series:

[image]

- `(*)` used the standard formula for geometric series.
- `(**)` notes that for a summation of powers of `n`, the highest power dominates (`1/2`). Assume the stopping condition to be some small constant, be it `n = 1`:

[image]

Note that as `n` increases, the `2^(1 - ...)` term vanishes. The first term is therefore bounded from above by `O(n)`, which is overshadowed by the second term.

> The time complexity of `√n`-way merge-sort is therefore `O(n^1.5)`, which is worse than the `O(n log n)` complexity of 2-way merge-sort.